# node-red no response from server when it works perfectly in chrome

Tags: node-red

I have a very simple GET request in node red.  It gets data from an https source for solar forecasting.  If I put the URL straight into Chrome or Firefox it immediately returns the data packet in JSON format.  All was working well until I upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04.
Now I am getting "no response from server"
What should I be looking at?  I had to do a fresh install of node'js, npm and node-red on my Ubuntu machine after the upgrade (which corrupted just about everything) and then import all my flows.  All the others are working, its just this one that is faulty.

Simple response in JSON to be parsed and sent into my influxdb

Comment: Did you change versions of nodejs as part of the upgrade (very likely). Are you sure there are no errors even in the Node-RED console logs?

Comment: Most likely your solar device is not confirming to HTTP spec and later versions of nodejs will reject if the headers are not terminated with nlcr

Comment: I have searched journalctl for any lines with 'nodered' or 'node-red' in the grep statement and it returns nothing.  I have run jounalctl -n100 immedialtely before and after triggering the error and seen no difference in the final lines of journalctl.

 I have looked in my home/.node-red folder and there is no log.  I have looked at settings.js and logging is set to info.   Where might I find the logs?

Comment: This will entirely depend on how you are running node-red. But assuming it is running as a service on Linux the command is `journalctl -u nodered` or `node-red-log`